# Doctrine not using lazy fetch mode by default in relationships?

Tags: php, doctrine

I Have this

```
User {
    ...
    /**
     * @var Country
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PersistenceModel\Country")
     */
    private $country;

}
```

I'm confuse about how this relationship is loaded:

**QUESTION**: as Doctrine documentation specifies, the default type of fetching relationships is Lazy. This means that I should expect a second query when requesting the related item (in this case Country). 
However, I never see that second query in my sql Log (even if I do `$user->getCountry()->getName()` or `$user->getCountry()`), and instead I ONLY see the query below. Magically, my User entity has all the data without any obvious second query, and the only query I can see is not using any JOIN. How is that possible?

```
 SELECT 
    t0.id AS id_1, 
    t0.name AS name_2, ...
    t0.country_id AS country_id_7 
 FROM user t0 
 WHERE t0.name = '....' 
 LIMIT 1
```

In order to check that there was no problem with my sql log configuration, I was using also in the php code:

```
$this->em->getConnection()
        ->getConfiguration()
        ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger())
    ;
```

This displayed the same (and UNIQUE) query I posted above

Answer (score 0):

The `$user->getCountry()` returns a Proxy and does not result in a query to the database. This is the default lazy call.

You can verify that by running `echo get_class($user->getCountry());` before that call.

If you really want to produce a query, call `$user->getCountry()->getName()` or any other getter from that entity. The `$user->getCountry()->getId()` will work without a query though, because the ID is already known from the foreign key.

Comment: I know that theorically it should happen that. But is not happening...I have still exactly the same scenario I explained above

Comment: Well this is the default Doctrine setup, the data don't come up magically. If your setup is different run a debugger and verify step by step what's happening under the hood. Who uses echo since excellent [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) exists?

Comment: @FranciscoAlbert There's no code in your question that would cause a second query to run. Just calling `$user->getCountry()` will return a proxy object, as this answer explains, and you haven't said that you're doing anything more than that. What code are you running that you are expecting to run the second query?

Comment: I aggee, I didn't specify that I tried also $user->getCountry()->getName(). With XDEBUG I was no lucky either, I get everything, but I don't know how is done that